# $http post via an angularjs service

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I use the code below. The content of `dataService` is all the $http possible in my application. In the controller, I consume this function. The function call a Web Api service, this one is called and return the right response. In the function `customerToggleSuccess` the data is `undefined`. I don't understand why.

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myApp')
        .factory('dataService', ['$q', '$http']);

    function dataService($q, $http,) {

        return {
            customerToggleActive: customerToggleActive
        };

        function customerToggleActive(customerId, index) {

            var customer = {
                "id": customerId,
                "index": index
            };

            return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'api/customer/validtoggle/',
                headers: {
                },
                transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
                },
                data: customer
            })
            .then(customerToggleData)
            .catch(customerToggleError)
        }

        function customerToggleData(response) {
            return response.data;
        }

        function customerToggleError(response) {
        }
    }

}());

(function () {

    angular.module('myApp')
        .controller('customerController', ['$scope', 'dataService', '$http', '$log', CustomerController]);

    function CustomerController($scope, dataService, $http, , $log) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.activeToggle = function (customerId, index) {

            dataService.customerToggleActive(customerId, index)
                .then(customerToggleSuccess)
                .catch(customerToggleCatch)
                .finally(customerToggleComplete);

            function customerToggleSuccess(data) {
                $log.info(data);
            }

            function customerToggleCatch(errorMsg) {
            }

            function customerToggleComplete() {
            }

        } 

    }

}());
```

Comment: In the $http you configure a transformRequest function but don't return anything. Maybe this is the issue ? [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 0):

Simply return the $http promise,

```
  return $http({
             method: 'POST',
             url: 'api/customer/validtoggle/',
             headers: {
             },
             transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
             },
             data: customer
         })
```

you can access it by,

```
dataService.customerToggleActive(customerId, index)
      .then(function (response) {
             // do your stuff
      })
```

or, you can do,

```
function dataService($q, $http,) { 
    var defer = $q.defer();
    ....
    ....
    $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: 'api/customer/validtoggle/',
         headers: {
         },
         transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
         },
         data: customer
     })
     function customerToggleData(response) {
        defer.resolve (response.data);
    }

    function customerToggleError(response) {
        defer.reject(response);
    }
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Comment: In the second case no change, in the first case how treat the promise ?

Comment: you can use the promise the same way you were doing earlier

Answer (score 0):

Like this ,

```
(function () {
        angular.module('myApp')
            .factory('dataService', ['$q', '$http']);

        function dataService($q, $http,) {

            return {
                customerToggleActive: customerToggleActive
            };

            function customerToggleActive(customerId, index) {

                var customer = {
                    "id": customerId,
                    "index": index
                };

                return $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'api/customer/validtoggle/',
                    headers: {
                    },
                    transformResponse: function (data, headers) {
                    },
                    data: customer
                })

            }      
        }

    }());
```